# Configure wampserver 2.5 to internet access

Tags: apache, hosting, wampserver

I was trying to configure apache server to be accessible from other WAN computers

Tried this and other procedures that I have found in different forums but it still isn't accessible:

*Set my rooter port forwording to 8080

*configured the httpd.conf to listen to port 80 and granted all access to DocumentRoot directory

Comment: Why do you forward port 8080 when your server is told to listen on port 80?

Comment: Apart from that you really should think twice if you really want to do that. You will expose your system in the internet. And you want to do that with exactly that operating system that is notoriously known for its security issues: MS-Windows. That is not a good idea...

Comment: I've changed the port listening to 8080 aswell, didn't work. 

I'm intending to host the website from home just for a while ..

Comment: There are many aspects that must be right. Let's start with DNS: how will the domain name get resolved? Typically one does not have a static ip address at home. Next: what do you mean by "isn't accessible"? How have you tested? From where have you tested?

Comment: You can still adress requests to a dynamic ip

What I need is help to configure wampserver to be accessible from other computers in WAN.

Comment: So you want to access by IP address, not by host name. OK. Any answers to my questions?

Comment: That's a lot of help !

Comment: Sorry, but what do you want? I tried to start helping with finding out where the issue is. I asked you a few simple questions. But you do not reply but get sarcastic. Sorry. Help yourself then.

Comment: This is irrelevant. I am sorry, I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that Wamp Server is running fine on your localhost.
Suppose your IP Address is 192.168.5.10:8080 to access wamp Server and the same you want to access from other PC on WAN. Then Click on "Put Online" as mentioned in the Screenshot.
[image]

It will restart the wamp Server. Just wait until the Wamp Color Become green and you will be able to access your localhost wampserver website on your network.
I hope this will work for you